# Mean/ Expected Value of $X^4$

Tags: probability, statistics, average

$\def\Var{\mathop{\rm Var}}$Can anyone help me prove that Expected Value of $X^4$ is $3\Var(X)^4$, if the Expected Value of $X$ is zero and $\Var(X)$ is the Variance of $X$?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, notice that since $E(X)=0, Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2=E(X^2)$

Comment: Can you check the expression that you wrote in the question? Because as martini pointed out in his answer, the current expression seems to be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I do notice that, actually I want to find the Variance of X^2..which leads to E(X^4) - [E(X^2)]^2

Comment: Yup, it's wrong. Refer my comment on martini answer

Comment: Could you please edit your question so that the correct formulation is visible?

Comment: There is no way to calculate the fourth moment, if you only know the first and second moment. Even the suggested change in Martini's answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

That is wrong in general. Suppose for $\def\R{\mathbb R}\lambda \in \R^+$ we have $\def\P{\mathbb P}\P(X=\lambda) = \P(X=-\lambda) =\frac 12$, then for any $k$ we have
$$ \def\E{\mathbb E}\E(X^k) = \frac 12\bigl(\lambda^k + (-\lambda)^k\bigr) = \begin{cases} \lambda^k & k \text{ even}\\ 0 & k \text{ odd}\end{cases} $$
Hence $\E(X) = 0$, ${\rm Var}(X) = \E(X^2) = \lambda^2$ and $\E(X^4) = {\rm Var}(X)^2$. So we have $\E(X^4) = 3{\rm Var}(X)^4$ only if $\lambda^4 = 3\lambda^8$, which is wrong in general.

Comment: Yes, wrong expression.
It's actually 3*[Variance(X)]^2, I don't know where the 3 comes from